# Java: Execute /cmd /c start path-with-spaces\program.exe

Tags: java, process

I've read a lot about the question but the answers I have found don't work completely.

I try to run this code :

```
String[] args = {"cmd","/c","start","C:\\Program Files\\XML Marker\\xmlmarker.exe"};
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
Process pr = pb.start();      
//Process pr = rt.exec(args);
```

As I have spaces in my path, I use String array to pass the arguments to the Process
But ... it opens a DOS command window but doesn't launch my program, as if the parameters where ignored

I tried with rt.exec(args) and pb.start() ... same result

Could someone give me some advice please ?
Thank you.

Comment: actually you need to put an empty title: `start,"","Path\\To\\file"`

Comment: what is "/c" in this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to have a "start" and "cmd" at the same time. You can safely take out "start". If you use a parameter enclosed in quotes with the "start" command, it treats it as a Title for a new command window.

Comment: Thanks Arun, I removed the start argument and it works perfectly !

Answer (score 5):

Try adding quotes around the path by inserting escaped quotes in your string, as follows:

```
String[] args = {"cmd","/c","start","\"C:\\Program Files\\XML Marker\\xmlmarker.exe\""};
```

Notice the `\"` at the start and end of the path string.